# Use consistency level in Phantom-dsl and Cassandra

Tags: scala, cql3, phantom-dsl

Currently using --

```
cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.17 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
```

Using phantom-dsl 1.12.2 , Scala 2.10 ..

I can't figure out how to set consistency levels on queries.

There are predefined functions `insert()` , `select()` as part of `CassandraTable` .. How can I pass the consistency level to them ?

```
insert.value(....).consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
```

does not work and fails with an error ( probably because this appends a "USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM" at the end of the query). Here's the actual exception I get

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:424 no viable alternative at input 'CONSISTENCY'
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:122) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:120) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:186) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:45) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:754) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:576) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.2.0-rc3.jar:na]
```

I see from the documentation and discussion on [this](https://github.com/websudos/phantom/pull/304#issuecomment-136383739) pull request that I could do a `setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)` on a SimpleStatement, but I would prefer not rewrite all the different insert statements.

**UPDATE**

Just to close the loop on this issue. I worked around this by creating a custom `InsertQuery` and then using that instead of the one provided by `final def insert` in `CassandraTable`

```
  def qinsert()(implicit keySpace: KeySpace) = {
     val table = this.asInstanceOf[T]
     new InsertQuery[T, M, Unspecified](table, CQLQuery("INSERT into keyspace.tablename", consistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all there is no `setValue` method inside phantom and the API method you are using is missing an `=` at the end.

The correct structure is:

`Table.insert
  .value(_.name, "test")
  .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum)`

As you are on stackoverflow, an error stack trace and specific details of what doesn't work is generally preferable to "does not work".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated the question with the actual error I get when I use `.consistenceyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)`

Comment: @Kal It means the phantom versioning logic might not be adequately accounting for the moment Datastax rolled their change to consistency parsing. 

Phantom has to read the Cassandra version and then apply consistency based on that, hence the issue. I will have a look at this further. Although this is tested and works, `2.0.17` seems to break.

Comment: Hi @flavian -- Thanks again. I've been able to narrow it down to the fact that basically the `USING` is no longer part of the CQL3 api. If I do this `session.newSimpleStatement(insert query).setConsistencyLevel`, and then issue `session.execute(..)` , it works. This command does happen in class `ExecutableQuery -- def statement()` , but there does not seem to be anyway to override `def consistencyLevel: Option[ConsistencyLevel]`

Comment: @Kal When you use the phantom method, internally phantom uses the same `session.newSimpleStatement` to set the level, somehow this is failing but we do actually have tests for this. The only thing that can be wrong is that we don't go far enough in Cassandra versions. The tests look like: if Cassandra.Version great than x, do this, otherwise do that. Hope this makes sense, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out how to properly set the consistency level using phantom-dsl.

Using a statement you can do the following:

```
statement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
```

Also, take a look on the test project I've been working to help guys like you with examples using phantom-dsl:

https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom